# Activating Facebook after permanent deactivation

Tags: facebook

Someone has hacked my Yahoo email and my Facebook password recently (about 2 weeks ago) and deactivated my Facebook account permanently, so I contacted Yahoo help center and succeeded to get my email back and changed my password. But what can I do about the permanent deactivation of my Facebook account?

Comment: Was it *deleted* or *deactivated*? Deleted is permanent. Deactivated is not.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not permanently deleted, it stays there until you're ready to return. Just log back in when your ready unless you delete through this link

- https://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account

If you deleted through that link then you used the wrong procedure and it will Be deleted in 14 Days